# How to rectify transformer exception

Tags: android

I am doing application with parsing XML file. I used TransformerFactory to modify XML file. when i use TransformerFactory in android 2.2 version its working fine, at the same time when using TransformerFactory in android version 2.1 i am getting Transformer exception. Can anybody know how to rectify transformer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransformerFactory` is API level 8 and above only, so it's not present in 2.1. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html).